# Conditions for random numbers in Javascript. How do I get this condition to work?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my code is not working. I am teaching myself JavaScript and here's the code I used. It is for a version of the blackjack game. I want the getRandomCard() function to return a number between 1 and 13. However, I want it to return 11 when the randomNumber is 1 and for it to return 10 when the randomNumbers are 11, 12 and 13.

Why isn't it working?

```js
function getRandomCard() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *13) + 1
    if (randomNumber = 1) {
        return 11
    } else if (randomNumber = 11, 12, 13 ) {
        return 10
    } else {
        return randomNumber
    }
}

console.log(getRandomCard())
```

Here is what I did. But when I run it, all it returns is the number 11.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: To compare numbers, use `==` instead of `=`, i.e. `if(randomNumber == 1)`. See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). To compare multiple number, use [||](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator. i.e. `else if(randomNumber == 11  || randomNumber == 12 || randomNumber ==13)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

1. `if (randomNumber = 1) {`

   This `=` is an assignment operator. If you wat to compare you need to use either `==` or `===`
2. `else if (randomNumber = 11, 12, 13 ) {`

   This should be something like

   `randomNumber == 11 || randomNumber == 12  || randomNumber == 12`

   or you can use `includes` function to check if the number is in array. Like this:

   `[11, 12, 13].includes(randomNumber)`

```js
function getRandomCard() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *13) + 1
    if (randomNumber == 1) {
        return 11
    } else if ([11, 12, 13].includes(randomNumber)) {
        return 10
    } else {
        return randomNumber
    }
}
console.log(getRandomCard());
```